# How prevalent is the use of old style names for ions (e.g. ferric, ferrous) outside the classroom

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature

In teaching my preparatory chemistry courses, I'm constantly wondering whether or not I should be having students memorize the "old names" of common multivalent monatomic cations, such as plumbic for lead (IV), plumbous for lead (II), etc.  Every year I teach the course, this information seems increasingly outdated, as I find that I'm coming across these less and less in my general reading.  To the readers I'd like to pose this question: In your practical experience, particularly in industry or other fields outside chemistry, do you still employ this style of referring to ions and compounds?

Comment: Im sure the answer will always be opinion based, but certainly I've *never* been taught these old names. The only time I see them day-t0-day is on labels of old chemical containers, but even then theres usually an accompanying molecule formula. I feel like students hate having to remember things (nomenclature wise) without trying to coax them into learning trivial names that are neither endorsed by IUPAC nor used by anyone under the age of 50.